# accessing Resource in ACTIVEX DLL from aspx page

Tags: asp.net, iis, vb6, activex

I have an activeX dll that was written in vb6. Inside that code it uses  the `LoadResPicture()` to load an image that it then sends to a printer (using `PaintPicture`)

If I call this DLL using an ASPX page, that hosted on a Windows 2008 box running IIS 7.0, the image doesn't print.

If I call this DLL using a VBS script on the very same server, the image prints fine.

The image used to print fine when the aspx page was hosted on a Windows 2000 Server.

Here is the VBS Code:

```
Dim CheckCtl
set CheckCtl = CreateObject("CHECKCONTROL.CHECK")

CheckCtl.FBOAccountID = 2765
CheckCtl.includesignature = True
CheckCtl.Amount = 500.00
CheckCtl.CheckDate = #04/06/2011#
CheckCtl.Payee_L1 = "Donald Trump"
CheckCtl.Payee_L2 = "10 Park Place"
CheckCtl.Payee_L3 = "Atlantic City, NJ 00011"
CheckCtl.Payee_L4 = ""
CheckCtl.Notes = "This is a test check"
CheckCtl.SubmittedBy = "Accountant"

dim lSuccess
lSuccess = CheckCtl.Printcheck()
```

Here is the ASPX VB.NET Code:

```
Dim CheckCtl As checkcontrolNET.Check
CheckCtl = New checkcontrolNET.Check
CheckCtl.FBOAccountId = 2765
CheckCtl.IncludeSignature = True
CheckCtl.Amount = 500.0
CheckCtl.CheckDate = "04/06/2011"
CheckCtl.Payee_L1 = "Donald Trump"
CheckCtl.Payee_L2 = "10 Park Place"
CheckCtl.Payee_L3 = "Atlantic City, NJ 00011"
CheckCtl.Payee_L4 = ""
CheckCtl.notes = "This is a test check"
CheckCtl.SubmittedBy = "Accountant"

Dim lSuccess As Boolean
lSuccess = CheckCtl.printcheck()
Response.Write(lSuccess)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Is your server 64-bit by any chance? According to MSDN, the .Net version of that function is only supported on 32-bit versions so its possible the same may be true for the VB6 version.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms652936.aspx

Comment: The server is 32-bit. It also runs fine on that server when I run it via a commandline vbs script.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that VBS part. I'm going to lean towards what @Kev said regarding permissions. On the server run the command `dcomcnfg` which will bring up the Component Services manager. Tip open `Console Root, Component Services, Computers, My Computer, DCOM Config and look for your component in there. Right-click it, select properties and go to the Security tab. You might have to change either or both of the first two adding the security account that your app pool runs under.

Comment: I don't see it listed under DCOM Config. Would it be listed by guid?

Comment: Its possible. Did you `regsvr32` the DLL?

Comment: It's been registered. If it weren't it wouldn't work via the VBS script.

Comment: I tried to determine the guid by poking around the registry, but I still don't see the corresponding guid under component services.

Comment: Just to make sure that you've got the right GUID, go to regedit and do a search for `CHECKCONTROL`. You should find it in `HKCR\AppID\{GUID}` and also `HKCR\AppID\CHECKCONTROL.DLL`, right? That's the GUID that you want to look for in DCOMCNFG. You should also find it in `HKCR\CLSID\{GUID}` but those GUIDs are actually different GUIDs.

Comment: I don't see it listed under HKCR\AppID

Comment: It sounds like you're missing some registry keys. If you read the post below they talk about un-registering it, putting the DLL in `System32` and re-registering it. See if that makes it show up in DCOMCNFG. http://bytes.com/topic/asp-classic/answers/59512-call-server-createobject-failed-while-checking-permissions-access-denied-object#post221291

Comment: I unregistered it, and moved the dll to system32 and re-registered it. It still doesn't show up in dcomcnfg and it still doesn't show up in the registry under HRCR/AppID. It also still doesn't print the LoadResPicture()

Answer (score 1):

I found COM+ approach for VB ActiveX with IIS wacky. I hope you have control over VB6 Dlls code and if so, try putting this code into the VB6 class you are trying to instantiate.

```
Private moScriptCtx As ScriptingContext

Public Sub OnStartPage(SC As ScriptingContext)

    Set moScriptCtx = SC

End Sub
```

You can now access Request,Response,Server etc as properties of the moScriptCtx object. ASP automagically calls `OnStartPage()` for you during the CreateObject execution.

[EDIT]

This may not be useful in your case if you are not useing ASP's intrinsic properties, but try enabling this on COM+ management console.

```
Fire up the COM+ management consoleo    
Find the COM+ Application in questiono    
Find the applicable component in the 'Components' folder
Right click on it and choose properties
Select the Advanced tab
Check the 'Allow IIS Intrinsic Properties' checkbox
```

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/distributedservices/archive/2010/04/28/iis-intrinsic-properties-are-disabled-by-default-on-windows-2008-and-windows-2008-r2.aspx

Comment: Why would I need to access the request, response, or server object within this control? How is this going to solve my problem?

Comment: What does your LoadResPicture() method do? Can you post that code also?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds suspiciously like a permissions problem. I suspect that your Windows 2000 server ran IIS under the `SYSTEM` account and probably did the same with the old `ASPNET` worker process account.

Check that the account that the site runs under has permissions to print. Depending on how you've secured the site this could be any one of:

- The application pool identity
- A specific anonymous account
- The `IUSR` account

Comment: I'm running against the Classic .NET App pool. Under advanced properties that app pool says NETWORKSERVICE under identity. Does that mean I need to give the networkService read rights to the CheckControl.dll file?

Comment: @aheho - do you get any exceptions thrown?

Comment: No. It's almost as if the loadResPicture call and the following paintpicture gets ignored. Everything else on the form prints fine.